# Mystery of for loop (Clojure)

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am a newbie in clojure and was implementing Kadane's algorithm. The quality of the code is pretty bad and which is fine as i want to write the bad code first and then gradually improve. Somehow my for loop is not executing. Please guide

I have tried various combinations of prints but failed hence i come to you

```clj
(defn max-contigous-sub-array [list]
  (let [local-sum (atom (first list))
        global-sum (atom (first list))]
    (doseq [x (rest list)]
      (do
        (reset! local-sum (max x (+ @local-sum x)))
        (if (> @local-sum @global-sum)
          (reset! global-sum @local-sum))))
    @global-sum))
```

Comment: Per others' comments, `for` in `clojure` is list comprehension.  The imperative for-loop in `clojure` is actually `doseq`.  
Couple other things: (1) `max` should be used as `(max 3 4)` not `(max [3 4])`;  (2) Usage of `atom` (mutable state) + for-loop is typically replaced by `reduce` + running state in functional programming.  E.g. `(reduce (fn [[global-max local-max] x]  ...) [(first xs) (first xs)] (rest xs))`.

Comment: @rmcv i will try this approach, thanks!.

Comment: Hi @rmcv i did not understand, could you elaborate with an example code. Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/rmcv/4aaa33d1268b62e3577076dd008fc4f8 

Note that `reduce` is like looping on a state while iterating list elements.  This is like the imperative for-loop except the state (values like global-max, local-max) is build up in an immutable way.  Added bonus is that you can replace `reduce` with `reductions` whenever you want to see what is going on!  (Of course you can also do that in imperative for-loop with println)

Comment: Hey @rmcv thanks a lot, it's really clever implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `for` function in clojure is not an imperative loop but a function for producing lazily-generated list comprehensions. For your case, you should use the `doseq` loop.

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq

The reason your current loop is never being executed is because you're never doing anything with the lazy sequence returned by the `for` function, and so the lazy seq is never evaluated.